# vol$(\Omega)=\sum$vol$Q_j$ where $Q_j$ are open boxes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with $C^\infty$ boundary. For every $\epsilon >0$ there exist $l<m$ and open disjoint boxes $Q_1,...,Q_m\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

(a) $\bigcup_{j=1}^{l}\overline{Q_j}\subset\Omega$

(b) $\Omega\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^{m}\overline{Q_j}$

(c) vol$(\Omega)-\epsilon<\sum_{j=1}^{l}$vol$(Q_j)\leq$vol$(\Omega)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{m}$vol$(Q_j)<$vol$(\Omega)+\epsilon$

Has anyone an idea how to start with the proof. I appreciate every input. Since I don't know how to start the proof I didn't get really far. It's really similar to the construction of lebesgue measure, but I still didn't get far.